# Publish RTMP stream to Red5 Server form iOS camera

Tags: ios, ffmpeg, h.264, rtmp, red5

Please look at following code, I have transformed `CMSampleBufferRef` into `AV_CODEC_ID_H264` but I don't know how to transmit it to Red5 server.

Thanks,

```
- (void)  captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput
  didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer
     fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection {

//NSLog(@"This is working ....");

  // [connection setVideoOrientation: [self deviceOrientation] ];

if( !CMSampleBufferDataIsReady(sampleBuffer) )
{
    NSLog( @"sample buffer is not ready. Skipping sample" );
    return;
} else {

    if (captureOutput == videoOutput) {


        CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
        CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, 0);

        // access the data
        float width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(pixelBuffer);
        float height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(pixelBuffer);

        //float bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRowOfPlane(pixelBuffer, 0);
        unsigned char *rawPixelBase = (unsigned char *)CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(pixelBuffer, 0);


        // Convert the raw pixel base to h.264 format

        if (codec == nil) {

            codec = 0;
            context = 0;
            frame = 0;

            fmt = avformat_alloc_context();
            //avformat_write_header(fmt, NULL);

            codec = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_H264);

            if (codec == 0) {
                NSLog(@"Codec not found!!");
                return;
            }

            context = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);

            if (!context) {
                NSLog(@"Context no bueno.");
                return;
            }

            // Bit rate
            context->bit_rate = 400000; // HARD CODE
            context->bit_rate_tolerance = 10;
            // Resolution

            // Frames Per Second
            context->time_base = (AVRational) {1,25};
            context->gop_size = 1;
            //context->max_b_frames = 1;
            context->width = width;
            context->height = height;
            context->pix_fmt = PIX_FMT_YUV420P;

            // Open the codec
            if (avcodec_open2(context, codec, 0) < 0) {
                NSLog(@"Unable to open codec");
                return;
            }

            // Create the frame
            frame = av_frame_alloc();
            if (!frame) {
                NSLog(@"Unable to alloc frame");
                return;
            }
        }

        context->width = width;
        context->height = height;

        frame->format = context->pix_fmt;
        frame->width = context->width;
        frame->height = context->height;

        //int nbytes = avpicture_get_size(context->pix_fmt, context->width, context->height);
        //uint8_t* outbuffer = (uint8_t*)av_malloc(nbytes);
//            AVFrame *pFrameDecoded = avcodec_alloc_frame();
//            int num_bytes2 = avpicture_get_size(context->pix_fmt, frame->width, frame->height);
//            uint8_t* frame2_buffer2 = (uint8_t *)av_malloc(num_bytes2 * sizeof(uint8_t));
//            avpicture_fill((AVPicture*)pFrameDecoded, frame2_buffer2, PIX_FMT_YUVJ422P, 320, 240);

        frame->pts = (1.0 / 30) * 60 * count;
        avpicture_fill((AVPicture *) frame, rawPixelBase, context->pix_fmt, frame->width, frame->height);

        int got_output = 0;
        av_init_packet(&packet);
        //avcodec_encode_video2(context, &packet, frame, &got_output);

        do {
            avcodec_encode_video2(context, &packet, frame, &got_output);
            //avcodec_decode_video2(context, &packet, NULL, &got_output);
            //*... handle received packet*/

            if (isFirstPacket) {
                [rtmp sendCreateStreamPacket];
                isFirstPacket = false;
                //av_dump_format(fmt, 0, [kRtmpEP UTF8String], 1);
                avformat_alloc_output_context2(&ofmt_ctx, NULL, "flv", [kRtmpEP UTF8String]); //RTMP
            }

            packet.stream_index = ofmt_ctx->nb_streams;
            av_interleaved_write_frame(ofmt_ctx, &packet);
            count ++;

            //[rtmp write:[NSData dataWithBytes:packet.data length:packet.size]];


        } while(got_output);

        // Unlock the pixel data
        CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, 0);

        //[rtmp write:[NSData dataWithBytes:packet.data length:packet.size]];

    } else {

    }
}   }
```